# Excel - if column a data is same, stack column b in row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with a data set of two columns. Column A is a set of IDs and Column B is email addresses.

Column A is all unique, but there will be duplicates in Column B.

I'm needing to find the duplicate instances in Column B and consolidate the unique data from Column A in rows next to the first instance of the data in Column B.

So example:

```
1234.   Abc@mail.com
1256.   Abc@mail.com
1357.   Abc@mail.com
```

I need this to turn into:

```
Abc@mail.com.    1234.   1256.  1357.
```

Make sense?

Comment: This can be done with VBS (or other languages) but is a bit of a scripting exercise.

Comment: *I need this to turn into* Does the final value "1234.   1256.  1357. " occupies Bx single cell, or this is Bx-Dx range?

Answer (score 0):

*An Array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get unique mail Id formula in cell `D71` , finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$71:$B$73, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$70:D70, $B$71:$B$73), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this formula in cell `E71`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it right.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$71:$A$73,SMALL(IF($B$71:$B$73=$D71,ROW($A$71:$A$73)-MIN(ROW($A$71:$A$73))+1),COLUMNS($E$71:E71))),"")}
  ```

---

**:Caveat:** *Purpose behind adding this portion is, to deal with another possibility, which is always possible.*

*Suppose you have more mail Ids like shown below, in random order.*

[image]

**N.B.**

- In this situation the formula I've used above, can be used, but you need to extend the cell references.
- For formula in cell `D71` cell references should be `($B$71:$B$76)`.
- Also for the formula in cell `E71` it should `$A$71:$A$76` & `$B$71:$B$76`.

---

*In case if location (cell range) changes, then you need to adjust cell references in the formula.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel with Office 365, with the new `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, and dynamic arrays, you can use the following:

- Make your data into a **Table** *I used the example of @RajeshS*
- To create a unique list of emails:

  `D3: =UNIQUE(Table1[Email])`

  - This will autopopulate the results down as far as necessary

---

```
`E3:  =TRANSPOSE(INDEX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Email]=D3),0,1))`
```

- This will autopopulate the results rightward
- Select E3 and fill down as far as needed

[image]

If you want to have the results ***in rows next to the first instance of the data in Column B***, then use this formula:

```
C2: =IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)=1,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(ID,B2=Email)),"")
```

[image]

If you don't have O365, you can create the results as a separate table easily with **Power Query** *(available in Excel 2010+)*

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Email", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Email"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [ID=number, Email=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "ID", each Table.Column([Grouped],"ID")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"ID", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ID.1", "ID.2", "ID.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ID.1", Int64.Type}, {"ID.2", Int64.Type}, {"ID.3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```